# Echelon form proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I searched other related posts but could not find the exact proof for the following:

> Given a matrix in echelon form how do I tell there are $0$ solutions or not? And if there are solutions, why is it so that if I fix the free variables all the basic variables get fixed?

Comment: If a matrix can be reduced in echelon form ( for system of equation) does is ensure >0 solutions , that is what i mean by first question